Is it possible to detect a photon using gravity without information about its emission and absorption?
Is it possible to detect a photon using gravity without information about its emission and absorption?
Speculation. Body No.1 emits a photon and changes its momentum. The photon passes by body No.2 and is deflected. Body No.3 absorbs the photon and changes its momentum. The sum of the changes in momentum of bodies No.1 and No.3 is nonzero, meaning the photon transferred momentum by gravity to body No.2 as it passed by.
Simplified idea of a seemingly feasible experiment. A thin-walled chamber with rarefied gas has sensors (probably optical) for the distribution of density and/or temperature in the gas volume. One side of the chamber is open to space, from where ultra-high-energy photons can occasionally arrive. On the other side of the chamber is a dense detector for ultra-high-energy photons. The essence of the experiment is to search for small oscillations in the rarefied gas in the chamber that are not caused by electromagnetic interaction with the photon when the dense detector absorbs the ultra-high-energy photon.
The described speculation is about detecting even a photon using gravity, not about attempting to distinguish a photon from other particles using gravity.

A photon is the amount of energy that gets emitted into or absorbed from the electromagnetic field by an external system. What you are trying to do sounds like a weak measurement and quantum mechanics holds for these processes just fine. When you talk about "the photon changing momentum", you are basically just looking at a scattering process with one photon going in and a second, different photon coming out. That's an emission process (first photon emitted into the field) followed by an absorption process (second, different photon detected). There is a momentum change of the scattering body.

Certainly not in practice, and probably not even in theory.
In practice gravity is incredibly weak and gravitational effects of single particles are far, far too small to be measured by current technology.
For photons specifically there's an additional complication, which is that a short pulse of light (the closest classical analog of a photon) has a rather subtle interaction with spacetime, because its energy is frame dependent. So in isolation it doesn't curve spacetime, but as part of a system it may contribute to the curvature caused by the system as a whole i.e. it may contribute to the rest mass of the system.
We don't have a quantum theory of gravity yet, so any description of the gravitational effect of a single photon must be provisional.

If there is no sort of information on where the photon was emitted, the best intuitive answer is no.
However, if just the specifics of the emission are unknown (for example there is no way of knowing HOW it got emitted from a source) then you can quite confidently know the location where it was emitted from, even when having no information about how the mathematics of the emission.
In this scenario, you could thus utilise a random object nearby the observer (let it be the Sun), and use its strong gravity to find at what angle the photon gets deflected from the vicinity of the Sun.
Using this method theoretically, you can use the spacetime metric of the Sun by using either the Schwarzschild metric (metric ds^2) or the Einstein field equations (tensor g_μν) to find the mathematical structure of the curvature of spacetime of the Sun, and since photons travel in geodesics, you can use some math to calculate at what angle they deflect. The very specific angle at which the photon is deflected (measured in arcseconds) will thus give an estimate of where the photon was emitted from.
Of course, in order to do this experiment you must know already from the start the approximate location, and with today's technology there is no way of measuring information of only one singular photon, so in conclusion, the best answer for this question is no if we want to be realistic
